# How does enabling and disabling interrupts from the kernel prevent race conditions?

Tags: c, operating-system, interrupt, interrupt-handling

Only thing I can think of is enabling/disabling interrupts also disables kernel pre-emption.  This would make impossible (?) for multiple threads touching shared kernel data at the same time.

Is there something I'm missing (maybe because you can only enable/disable interrupts for one CPU at a time?)?

Answer (score 1):

In ye olde days of single processor systems, blocking interrupts was the method of locking kernel data structures. If Interrupt X were in the middle of changing something, it would not want to higher priority interrupt Y to execute and leave the data structures in an ambiguous state. Of course, X should only block interrupts for the minimum amount of time required.

In multi-processor systems you have to add software locking to prevent another process from mucking with system data structures while they are being modified (both for interrupts and system calls).

However, you still have to block interrupts. If interrupt X had data structures locked (or partially locked) and interrupt Y were able to execute, it could try to lock the same data structured and would wait forever.